# Program not reading file in

Tags: c++, file

It appears my program below is not reading in the files when I run it and type the name of the file. Could it be because it does not know where to look for them? Also my function to to return the amount of lines in the file only returns the memory address it appears.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
```

function to return the amount of characters in the txt file that is input:

```
int return_Characters(ifstream& in) 
{
    int characters = in.gcount();

    return characters;
}
```

function that is suppose to get the number of lines in the txt file and return that number as a double:

```
double return_lines(ifstream& in) 
{
    string name;
    double lines = 0;

    while(getline(in, name) ){
        int count = 0;
        lines = count++;
    }

    return lines;
}
```

main function:

```
int main() 
{
    string file_name;
    ifstream input_file;


    cout << "Please enter the name of your file" << endl;
```

do loop that reads in the file_name string that user inputs and runs the functions to get the amount of characters and lines in the txt file input by the user:

```
    do {
        getline(cin, file_name);
        cout << "checking" << ' ' << file_name << endl;

        input_file.open(file_name);

        int count_characters = return_Characters(input_file);
        cout << "the number of characters is equal to " << count_characters << '\n';

        double count_lines = return_lines(input_file);
        cout << "the number of lines in the file is equal to" << return_lines << '\n';

        input_file.close();

    }while(!file_name.empty());

    cout << "there was an error oepning your file. The program will not exit" << endl;


    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to grab yourself a GOOD book. You have a lot to learn. not just on C++, but general understanding of code logic.

Answer (score 2):

In the `return_lines` function, you declare `count` to be a local variable inside the loop. This means it will always be reset to zero each iteration, leading to `lines` also being set to zero all the time.

The other problem is that the `istream::gcount` function only returns the number of characters read from the last input operation, and as you don't do any input it will always return zero.

And there is *no* reason to use a `double` for the number of lines, as you will never have, say 12.3 lines in a file. Use `int`.

---

You should also check that the file operations succeed. While you do it correctly in `return_lines`, you don't check that the opening of the file was successful or not.

Comment: Plus, he actually prints the address of the function `return_lines` instead of the result of the function stored in `count_lines`.

Answer (score 2):

This function doesn't do what you describe it as. It returns "the number of characters read in the latest read operation (e.g. if you do `in.getline()`, then this line would return the length of that line).

int return_Characters(ifstream& in) 
    {
        int characters = in.gcount();

```
    return characters;
}
```

To find out the size of the file, you need to seek to the end, get the position, and then seek back to the start. Although this is unreliable for text files on certain systems, because `newline` is two bytes in the file, and only counts as "one character" in C. If you want to count the characters in the file, and number of lines, then count the number of characters in each line (make your `return_lines` also take a parameter for number of characters it's read).